# I need an explanation of insulation

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

Clothes reduce the heat loss to keep a person warm. But if the person is always producing more heat than the clothes are losing it, his temperature will rise indefinitely. Is it because as the object being insulated heat up, the heat loss through the insulation increases (due to larger temperature differential=more heat transfer) until it is equal to the amount of heat being generated? So in winter a naked person is losing more heat than he is producing, and it's only good if heat lost=heat produced?

Comment: I can not explain the reason why, but _air_ is a very good insulator _IF_ you can keep it from moving.  Most of the practical insulation in our clothing and in our homes works by trapping air, and restricting is ability to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chief physics concept needed to understanding insulation by clothing is [Newton's Cooling Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Heat_transfer_version_of_the_law).

[image]

I'll apply a slightly simplified version of it here.

The *heat flux* (heat energy per unit of time) flowing from the body through the insulation to the outside world is given by:

$$\frac{\text{d}Q}{\text{d}t}=-hA(T_{body}-T_{outside})\tag{1}$$

where:

- the left hand side is the *heat flux*. The minus sign is needed because the heat flux is a *loss*,
- $h$ is the *heat transfer coefficient*,
- $A$ is the *surface area* shared by body and environment,
- $T_{body}$ and $T_{outside}$ are the body temperature and outside temperature, respectively.

$h$ depends primarily on the clothing. Thick, airy clothing has a low $h$ and is a good insulator while thin, flimsy clothing has a high value of $h$ and less insulating capacity.

When the value of $h$ is sufficiently low, the clothing will keep the body warm because the heat loss is small, so $T_{body}$ doesn't change in time (remember that the body tries hard to maintain a constant $T_{body}$).

The problem arises when $h$ is high (flimsy clothing) and $T_{outside}$ is low. Then according to $(1)$ heat loss becomes large and the body may not be able to maintain homeostasis (constant $T_{body}$). Hypothermia then becomes a real possibility.

Similar reasoning can be applied to high outside temperatures and potential overheating of the body.